# Add element to Firefox menu

Tags: firefox, menu

How to add some element in this menu (showned below)?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIaS5.png

I found how add element to toolbar menu and contex menu, but way to add something in this menu I could not find.

```
<!- Toolbar: -->
<menupopup id="menu_ToolsPopup">
<menuitem label="Test" oncommand="test.somefunction();"/>
</menupopup>

<!- Contex menu: -->
<popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
<menuitem label="Test" oncommand="test.somefunction();"
        insertafter="context-selectall"/>
</popup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

```
<popup  id="placesContext"> 
     <menuitem label="Test;" oncommand="test.somefunction();" /> 
</popup>
```

I installed DOM-inspector, to find solution. After it I investigated URL `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` and went to `#document -> #window -> popupset (mainPopupSet)`, where I by guess found needed element.

There is very good option "Copy XML" at DOM-inspector. It help me to find out what one or the other element to do.